# Using default WP menu functionality to link to custom post-type listing?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, menus, sub-menu

I'm completely starting over with a wordpress project that began a couple of weeks ago, and basically i'm totally discovering wordpress, so please bare with me.

I might be completely misunderstanding what has been coded until now, but I've been asked to generate a menu based on the "cutom-post-types" and their respective categories.

When using the

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
```

hook, I thought it would be enough.

**BUT**:
when editing the menu and it's content in the menu admin section it seems that I cannot have each category of a custom post-type to be listed UNDER each custom-post-type.
All I can do is select each category, like so :

Beauty
Campaigns
...

shops
...

Wich leads to this on the public site :

Beauty
Campaigns
...

Shops
...

My only wisgh is to be able to avoid hacking wordpress as much as possible, while finally having :

News
 Beauty
 Cmpaigns
...
Trends
 shops
...

in both the menu admin and the final public menu.

What did I miss ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet if you want them to show using the default drag and drop function is to register a custom taxonomy for the custom post type, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy.

You can also use the `taxonomies` parameter when you register your CPT function.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

The alternative is to make a custom filter for your nav menu that is populated from your custom post type, though in most cases I recommend the first option.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for this was to just use custom links that linked to example.com/post-type-slug...it's not the best solution, but it works.